# Something in hour() function get wrong?

Tags: r, lubridate

I don't understand why `hour()` got the output out of condition. I tried to subset time 15 mins interval only 8 to 16 (I meant after 8:00 should start at 8:15 and end at 16:00) o'clock but the output gone wrong.

From this :

```
library(lubridate)

startDate = "2018-10-01"
endDate = "2018-10-03"

timeseq <- data.frame(DateTime = seq(from=as.POSIXct(startDate),to=as.POSIXct(endDate),by="15 min"))

timeseq[(hour(timeseq$DateTime)>8 & hour(timeseq$DateTime)<=16),]
```

And I got this :

```
> timeseq[(lubridate::hour(timeseq$DateTime)>8 & lubridate::hour(timeseq$DateTime)<=16),]
[1] "2018-10-01 09:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 09:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 09:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 09:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 10:00:00 GMT"
[6] "2018-10-01 10:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 10:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 10:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 11:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 11:15:00 GMT"
[11] "2018-10-01 11:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 11:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 12:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 12:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 12:30:00 GMT"
[16] "2018-10-01 12:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 13:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 13:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 13:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 13:45:00 GMT"
[21] "2018-10-01 14:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 14:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 14:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 14:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 15:00:00 GMT"
[26] "2018-10-01 15:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 15:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 15:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 16:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 16:15:00 GMT"
[31] "2018-10-01 16:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-01 16:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 09:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 09:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 09:30:00 GMT"
[36] "2018-10-02 09:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 10:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 10:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 10:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 10:45:00 GMT"
[41] "2018-10-02 11:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 11:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 11:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 11:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 12:00:00 GMT"
[46] "2018-10-02 12:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 12:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 12:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 13:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 13:15:00 GMT"
[51] "2018-10-02 13:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 13:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 14:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 14:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 14:30:00 GMT"
[56] "2018-10-02 14:45:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 15:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 15:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 15:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 15:45:00 GMT"
[61] "2018-10-02 16:00:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 16:15:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 16:30:00 GMT" "2018-10-02 16:45:00 GMT"
```

Can anyone explain why and how to get the right result?

Comment: So what's the problem? For example, `16:15:00` has an hour that is <= 16. Ditto for `16:30:00`. The output is correct.

Comment: I think it is correct, since hour(timeseq$DateTime)>8 will result in 9 (so, first is 9:00) and hour(timeseq$DateTime)<=16 will result in 16 (so, the last will be 16:45, since the hour part is still 16). That is the "why" part, but i will not propose how the get the right result because i cannot test right now, sorry

Comment: Thank you, it's my misunderstanding on the function. I solved it using filter dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
 library(lubridate)
    timeseq%>%
      mutate(time=substr(DateTime,12,20))%>%
      filter(as.numeric(hms(time))>=32400, as.numeric(hms(time))<=57600)%>%
      select(-time)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `hour` and the output you're seeing is correct. For example, extracting the hour of `16:30:00` will return `16` which fulfils the condition `<= 16`. Ditto for `16:15:00` all the way up to `16:59:59`.

I assume you mean something like this in base R?

```
timeseq[
    timeseq$DateTime > as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s 08:00:00", startDate)) &
    timeseq$DateTime <= as.POSIXct(sprintf("%s 16:00:00", endDate)), ]
```